C declaring matrix variable with a variable declared as index
I'm wondering if it's possible in the C programming language to declare a 2D matrix with the second index declared as variable. Without using argv[n] command line.
For example
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int a;
  scanf("%d", &a);

  int matrix[][a];

  …SNIP…

I'm studying C for physics so I cannot try too many other things to try to resolve this.

Did you try it?  What happened when you did?

You need both dimensions for matrix unless the "array" is a function argument (effectively a pointer).

@dbush I recived a message that says "array size missing in matrix"

Maybe what you want is int *matrix[a]. This is an array of a pointers, and you can allocate the rows dynamically.

@Barmar or maintain contiguous memory by allocating a single dimensional array and then indexing into it using math to treat it as a two-dimensional array.

@Chris ...or don't index it using math but leave that to the compiler. Just use a pointer to VLA, available in standard C since the previous millennium.

If you do not know how many rows your matrix will have, then use pointers to arrays.
    size_t cols;
    scanf("%zu", &cols);

    int (*matrix)[cols];

    /* later in the code you need to decide how many rows you need */

    size_t rows;
    scanf("%zu", &rows);

    matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(*matrix));

    /* you can change it using realloc -*/

After allocation, you can use it the same way you'd use a normal array - for example:
matrix[3][4] = 345643;

Your array will have only one block of memory - the same as a "normal" array.
